# Foreground Notification action not sending broadcast

Tags: java, android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

My app has a service that runs full time. When app is on screen, service runs on background; and when app is off screen or closed, service runs with a foreground Notification.

**In this Notification, I have an action button that sends a broadcast. This button is not sending the broadcast and I don't know why, cause I tested the receiver and the receiver is working.**

Is something wrong with my Notification action or my Receiver?

Service Code:

```
public class TimerService extends Service {

private String TAG = TimerService.class.getSimpleName();

private TimerServiceReceiver receiver;

private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
private NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
Notification notification;

private boolean runningBackground;

public TimerService() {
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);


    createNotificationChannel();

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if(runningBackground){
        registerBroadcastReceiver();
        Log.v(TAG, "Service Broadcast registered.");

        createNotification();

    }else{
        mNotificationManager.cancel(ID_SERVICE);

    }

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

...

//=== NOTIFICATION ===/
private void createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;

        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}

private void createNotification(){
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExecuteExerciseActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("id_execution", idExecution);
    intent.putExtra("id_exercise", idExercise);
    intent.putExtra("position", position);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(ID_SERVICE, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    //Action Buttons & Intents
    Intent pauseIntent = new Intent(this, TimerServiceReceiver.class);
    pauseIntent.setAction(TIMER_PAUSE);
    PendingIntent pausePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, pauseIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.timer))
            .setContentText("00:00:00")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setPriority(PRIORITY_MIN)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SERVICE)

            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ntf_pause, getString(R.string.pause_timer), pausePendingIntent);


    notification = mBuilder.setOngoing(true)
            .build();

    startForeground(ID_SERVICE, notification);
}


private void updateNotificationText(String s){
    if(mBuilder != null && notification != null){
        mBuilder.setContentText(s);

        mNotificationManager.notify(ID_SERVICE, mBuilder.build());
    }
}



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.v(TAG, "ondestroy!");

    ...

    if(receiver != null) {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        Log.v(TAG, "Service Broadcast unregistered.");
    }
}

//=== BROADCAST RECEIVER ===/
public class TimerServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    public TimerServiceReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Message received by Service Broadcast!");

        if(intent != null){
            String action = intent.getAction();
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

            //Updates tvTimer
            if(action != null){
                switch(action){
                    case TIMER_PAUSE:
                        Log.v(TAG, "Notification sent Pause command!");
                        timerPause = true;

                        startForegroundService(new Intent(context, TimerService.class));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void registerBroadcastReceiver() {
    receiver = new TimerServiceReceiver();
    IntentFilter statusIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(TIMER_SERVICE_BROADCAST);
    statusIntentFilter.addAction(TIMER_START);
    statusIntentFilter.addAction(TIMER_PAUSE);
    statusIntentFilter.addAction(TIMER_STOP);

    // Registers the DownloadStateReceiver and its intent filters
   registerReceiver(receiver, statusIntentFilter);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Resolved... 
To make a broadcast receiver that runs on a service independent from the activity, I had to make the broadcast class Static and register it on manifest.

Broadcast:

```
public static class TimerServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private String TAG = TimerService.class.getSimpleName();

    public TimerServiceReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.v(TAG, "Message received by Service Broadcast!");

        if(intent != null){
            String action = intent.getAction();
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

            //Updates tvTimer
            if(action != null){
                switch(action){
                    case TIMER_PAUSE:
                        Log.v(TAG, "Notification sent Pause command!");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

manifest.xml:

```
     <receiver
        android:name=".services.TimerService$TimerServiceReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="RestartServiceWhenStopped">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="TIMER_START"/>
            <action android:name="TIMER_PAUSE"/>
            <action android:name="TIMER_STOP"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```